# Determine the best subnet mask for the 172.29.0.0 network, with 30 subnets and 1,100 host on each subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

This was a practice question I found [online](http://www.subnettingquestions.com/):

[image]

> **Question:** *You are designing a subnet mask for the 172.29.0.0 network. You want 30 subnets with up to 1100 hosts on each subnet. What subnet mask should you use?*

For some reason, I get the wrong answer when attempting to answer it.

Could someone have a go at calculating this, showing how they arrived at the answer?

I will update my question with the official answer shortly.

**Edit:**

The answer was 255.255.**248**.0.

Thanks bigjosh for showing how to reach that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are starting with 16 bits of assigned network (first two octects 172.29.x.x), and 16 bits you control (the last two octets). In binary that is...

AAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAA, xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx

30 subnets means you need 5 bits of sub-networks (2^5 = 32), so in binary that would look like...

AAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAA, SSSSSxxx, xxxxxxxx

That is a total of 16+5= 21 bits of mask. In octects that would look like...

255.255.248.0

This would give you room for 2^11= 2048 addresses on each subnet. When you account for the all zero and all ones addresses the you end up with 2046 possible hosts on each subnet which is plenty of room for your actual 1100 hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Online Subnet calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/), customize according to requirement.

[image: Check image]